# Return a range of elements of each list inside a list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

From a list `mylist = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` how can I get a new list of lists composed of the first two elements of each "inside" list e.i. `newlist = [[1, 2], [4, 5], [7, 8]]`? Is there a one-liner that can do this efficiently (for large lists of lists)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a list comprehension:

```
newlist = [sublist[:2] for sublist in mylist]
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer:

```
first_two = [sublist[:2] for sublist in mylist]
```

If having a list of tuples is ok, then a faster answer (2x by my measurements):

```
import operator
map(operator.itemgetter(0, 1), mylist)
```

Measurements:

```
t = timeit.Timer("[i[:2] for i in ll]", "ll = [[i, i + 1, i + 2] for i in xrange(1000)]")
t.timeit(10000)
>>> 2.2732808589935303

t2 = timeit.Timer("map(operator.itemgetter(0, 1), ll)", "import operator; ll = [[i, i + 1, i + 2] for i in xrange(1000)]")
t2.timeit(10000)
>>> 1.3041009902954102
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension.

```
 newlist = [x[:2] for x in mylist]
```